# Check if div contains any of these words and if so show this div

Tags: jquery, contains

Ive got a script which brings in some information regarding cars from a DVLA hook up.

```
$json = json_decode($response, true);
```

This then Shows on the page like this

```
Model: <?php echo $json['model'];  ?><BR>
```

However, what I want to do is check the cars Model, and if the Model matches 
AUDI RS4
AUDI RS6
LOTUS
MAZDA RX8

Then the page needs to show div B if, the mode is not on the exclude list then it can show div A.

So what I was thinking was something similar to this I found http://jsfiddle.net/9gHhD/

```
<cite class="fn"><?php echo $json['model'];  ?></cite>
```

Which for testing looks like:

```
<cite class="fn">AUDI RS4</cite>
```

and then the script

```
var searchText = 'AUDI RS4' , 'AUDI RS6';
$('cite.fn').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === searchText;
}) $("#excluded").css({display: "block"});
```

But this does not work. I dont know how to tell it to look for an array of different words? Or if this is even the best way to go about this?

Can anyone assist please

Comment: Look at https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ for an example of selecting based on text content.

Comment: I've checked your fiddle, Do you want to have `bla2bla` `blabla4` is red too?

Comment: Hi Sorry, That is not my fiddle, that is one I found to explain where I got the code from.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ Yes very similar - How would I ask it to check for multiple words? for example to that John and Geroge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check against multiple string as follows:

```
$('cite.fn').filter(function () {
    return ["blabla", "bla2bla"].includes($(this).text());
}).css('color', 'red');
```

Where as before you were limited to checking against a single string:

```
var searchText = 'blabla';

$('cite.fn').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === searchText;
}).css('color', 'red');
```

Specifically, `includes()` allows you to test against multiple string values.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know, Thank you.  return ["blabla", "bla2bla"].includes($(this).text());  Was where I was getting stuck. Thank you